# Redshift Query with Previous Week, Previous Week Hours, and Selected Day

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a table:

```
OrderDayHour              Orders   Program
2023-10-30 02:00:00.      10.         ss
2023-10-30 03:00:00.      20         ss
2023-10-30 04:00:00.      10        ss
2023-10-31  02:00:00.      10.         ss
2023-10-31. 03:00:00.      20         ss
2023-10-24 02:00:00.      10.         ss
2023-10-24 03:00:00.      40          ss
2023-10-24 04:00:00.      10        ss
2023-10-23 02:00:00.      10        ss
2023-10-23 01:00:00.      10        ss
```

I want to show output as

```
OrderDay.       Metric.                      TotalOrders
2023-10-31.        Selected Day            30
2023-10-24.       PreviousWeekCR.          50
2023-10-24.       PreviousWeek.            60
2023-10-30.        Selected Day            40
2023-10-23.       PreviousWeek.            20
```

So for 10-31 that is current day it has data only till 3rd hour so total orders for 10-23 PreviousWeekCR should also show till 3rd hour
But overall 10-23 has data total orders 60 so PreviousWeek should show that

Similarly 10-30 is not current day it has overall 40 orders, PreviousWeek overall has 20.
Since it's not current day it should not have PreviousWeekCR
How to write redshift query to calculate

I did try below but it's giving wrong results

I did try below but it's giving wrong results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.